# javascript for loop behaving weirdly when updating and logging an array inside the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have the following JavaScript code

```js
let logs = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  logs[j] = { j };
  console.log('logs', logs);
}
```

I expect the output to be as follows

```
logs [ { j: 0 } ]
logs [ { j: 0 }, { j: 1 } ]
logs [ { j: 0 }, { j: 1 }, { j: 2 } ]
logs [ { j: 0 }, { j: 1 }, { j: 2 }, { j: 3 } ]
logs [ { j: 0 }, { j: 1 }, { j: 2 }, { j: 3 }, { j: 4 } ]
logs [ { j: 0 }, { j: 1 }, { j: 2 }, { j: 3 }, { j: 4 }, { j: 5 } ]...
```

And this is what I get when I run this code in the nodejs console.

But when I check in browser, I get the following output

```
logs [ { j: 0 },
  { j: 1 },
  { j: 2 },
  { j: 3 },
  { j: 4 },
  { j: 5 },
  { j: 6 },
  { j: 7 },
  { j: 8 },
  { j: 9 } ]
```

for every iteration

Comment: you have to add 2 loops 1 for the vertical and another for horizontal.

Comment: You tagged this as node, what version are you running? Is this really all that is logged out, or ist your console just scrolling away?

Comment: @vikscool the loop works, put it in a node console or in your browser

Comment: You need to write a nested loop for this. The first loop needs to take care of the row number and the second loop needs to take care of the column number.

Comment: @Luca I'm using node 8.9.4. No that is not all that is logged out.. I should've probably mentioned that

Comment: @vikscool loop is giving the output as expected in the node console but in browser, it's not. I mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually doing what you expect it to. See the result in snippet below:

```js
let logs = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  logs[j] = {
    j
  }
  console.log('logs', logs)
}
```

Notice that the result shown in stack-snippet is different from the one shown in the browser. That's because stack-snippet's console evaluates the variable `logs` immediately, whereas (most) browsers evaluate the value when you *look* at them. So by the time you look at them, the variable has 10 elements in the array.

A simple change to verify this would be to stringify the array before logging to console. The snippet below should produce the expected results:

```js
let logs = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  logs[j] = {
    j
  }
  console.log('logs', JSON.stringify(logs));
}
```

Related: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot control how browser displays the `console.log` outputs. One way to show the values like you mentioned is to stringify the objects to JSON (read [what is JSON](https://www.json.org/)), and then show it on the console.

```js
let logs = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  logs[j] = { j };
  console.log('logs', JSON.stringify(logs));
}
```